# tool for getting the stack trace of on a file

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stack-trace

Do you know if there is a tool in Windows that is able to start a C++ application and, when there is an exception, is able to automatically save to file the stack trace information?

I now that there is the `dbghelp.dll` and `StackWalk64` function but I would  like rather to use some tool  instead of coding myself.

Right now I am also looking at `WinDebug` . I found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/how_to_get_a_stacktrace_with_windbg) that hen there is a crash, giving the following commands it prints out tons of diagnostic information, including off course the stack trace.

```
|* ~* kp
|* !analyze -v -f
|* lm
```

I am figuring out whether `WinDebug` can be automated but I would rather use some tool more simple to get just the stack trace. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Use Visual studio 2010 express edition from Microsoft Site. It has a pretty nice debugger.

It is free as well!!.

I am not sure if it can automatically save to file though. That may require automation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the system's [Dr.Watson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Watson_(debugger))(`drwtsn32`) to create a dump you can later use with windebug.